# How to remove SP2010 Ribbon Items?

Tags: 2010

I want the end user to be able to only access mostly CRUD features.

I don't want him seeing Version History button for example.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<HideCustomAction>` element

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx